# Binding entre componentes com XAML e C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Preciso que ao selecionar um item em um combobox, o textbox seja liberado para edição e seu preenchimento seja obrigatório, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse binding está sendo ativo ao clicar no botão novo, onde altero a propriedade IsEditing da minha classe ViewModel.

```
class ColectorsViewModel : Bindable
{
    bool isEditing;
    public bool IsEditing 
    {
        get { return isEditing; }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(ref isEditing, value);
            //ajusta o estado dos comandos
            NovoColetorCommand.CanExecute = IsViewing && selectedIndex >= 0;
            ExcluirColetorCommand.CanExecute = IsViewing && selectedIndex >= 0;
            CancelarEdicaoColetorCommand.CanExecute = isEditing;
            GravarColetorCommand.CanExecute = isEditing;
            // Notifica as properties IsEditing e IsViewing para serem reavaliadas.
            OnPropertyChanged("IsViewing");
        }
    }
}
```

no XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbIntColetaVal" 
    Text="{Binding Colectors.IntervaloColetaVal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
    Margin="563,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Grid.Column="1"
/>
```

e o Model:

```
public class Colectors : Bindable
{
    private int intervaloColetaVal;
    public int IntervaloColetaVal 
    {
        get { return intervaloColetaVal; }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(ref intervaloColetaVal, value);
            if (intervaloColetaVal <= 0)
            {
                AddError("O valor deve ser maior que zero(0)");
            }else
                RemoveErrors();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse comando `OnPropertyChanged("IsViewing");` não deveria ser para notificar a alteração da propriedade `IsEditing`?